# (Custom ViewBag with Where). Simple line but I cant make it work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewbag

```
ViewBag.cliente_id = new SelectList(db.cliente.Where(c => c.status_ativacao == 1), "id", "nome", manutencao.cliente_id);
```

It Still are returning all clients.
I need to return just who column 'status_ativacao' = value 1.
Am I sure doing this here or I need to do it on dropdownlist?

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="cliente_id">Cliente</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.DropDownList("cliente_id", (SelectList)ViewBag.Values, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cliente_id)
 <!--   <input type="submit" value="Atualizar Cliente" class="btn btn-default"/> -->
</div>
```

Comment: The `.Where()` clause you have shown will work fine and return only `cliente` where the value of `status_ativacao` is `1` (however putting a `SelectList` like that in `ViewBag` is bad practice and there is no point adding `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` because with your implementation you will never get any validation and your users cannot select the first item)

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert that query into a list first, like this:

```
ViewBag.cliente_id = new SelectList(db.cliente.Where(c => c.status_ativacao == 1).ToList(), "id", "nome", manutencao.cliente_id);
```

Also, change the Html.DropDownList in your view, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("cliente_id", (SelectList)ViewBag.cliente_id, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I assume you are setting this up in an action, how does the view look like?

Comment: Ok. You have to give the ViewBag.cliente_id to the DropDownList helper, you are giving it ViewBag.Values instead. I'm updating my answer.